# Do car hood sizes very depending on engine size?

Tags: honda, hood

I was at a salvage yard today and wanted to get a hood for my '13 Honda Accord 2.4L and the donor car was a 3.5L.

Does the hood size very on different trims/engine sizes? Would it fit my 2.4L?

Answer (score 1):

Hood sizes tend to change with body style.

But some hoods do have a power bulge for larger engines if necessary, but usually a power bulge or air scoop is a marketing thing to appeal to petrol heads or a styling thing.

When going to a scrappie, it’s a good idea to take a measuring stick with a note of the original size...  Saves wasted time and trips...